# Custom Bootstrap 4 UI in scaffolded Identity pages broken after upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, blazor, asp.net-core-6.0

I upgraded a .NET 5 blazor server app to .NET 6 and while .NET 6 apps now use Bootstrap 5 by default, I wanted to continue using Bootstrap 4, so I did not update my css or js files under wwwroot.

Most of the application UI looked the same after the upgrade except for the scaffolded Identity pages that I customized with Bootstrap 4 classes. Looking in the browser dev tools, I could see that the css being loaded for the main part of the app was Bootstrap 4 but the css being loaded for the Identity pages was Bootstrap 5 (which has breaking changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft announced the breaking change (moving from Bootstrap 4 to 5) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/identity-bootstrap4-to-5) and gave a [recommendation for those who wish to stay on Bootstrap 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/identity-bootstrap4-to-5#recommended-action).

The simplest solution:
Add the MSBuild property `IdentityUIFrameworkVersion` in the project (`.csproj`) file and specify Bootstrap 4:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <IdentityUIFrameworkVersion>Bootstrap4</IdentityUIFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```